# Appending data to saved file from RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Am writing data in .rtf Format from a RichTextBox using (Text is color coded )

```
 RichTextBox .SaveFile(path);
```

There is a 'Clear Text' button on the GUI on click of which clears the RichTextBox .

The problem arises when new data is printed on the RichTextBox instead of appending the data the   `RichTextBox .SaveFile(path)` method clears out the previous data and contains only the newly added data.

How can i append the data? StreamWriter is wrtitng the data in plain text i need it in .RTF.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: SaveFile does NOT append text to a existing file, it always overwrites it. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8bf5hy2e(v=vs.110).aspx The idea is that you load the content of the file into the RichTextBox, modify it and store the file "as is" right now in the control. If you need a different behaviour you'll have to write it.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the previous data in a variable, set the richTextBox's data to previous+new and then call the SaveFile method.

Comment: The data is rich text format with coloring and highlights.So if i store it in a string variable all that is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like saving from the rich text box overwrites the file. You can have a look at [this](http://p2p.wrox.com/vb-net-2002-2003-basics/9682-saving-rich-text-box-formatting.html) or [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2f35e36c-8e42-4823-a7ed-1ddfddc01b52/rich-text-box-appending-text-to-existing-rtf-document) for more info.

Some of the solutions suggested are saving to a different file, or reading, concatenating, and saving.

Comment: yup i believe there is no straight way of doing it. Am thinking of having another richtextbox with visibility as false storing values before clearing the text then appending it to the new values.

Comment: Sounds like a solution. Seems like the streams lose the formatting if my memory serves me right.

Comment: yes exaclty..Thanks for the help Omer Eldan and Noctis :) happy coding

Comment: No worries and happy coding back at you :). if you think this question is answered, feel free to mark either of the replies as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to append text to RTF file as you have already read from the comments.
What you can do, however, is use 2 RichEdit controls, one that reads the stream in using `EM_STREAMIN` message (this will preserve the char format) and concatenate the new data to it. For the preservation of the char format of the new data from the other RichEdit control (colors,fonts etc), you have to use `EM_GETCHARFORMAT` message on the selection of the new data you want to concatenate. And then, you need to use `EM_SETCHARFORMAT` message with `SCF_SELECTION OR SCF_WORD` to set the char format on the RichEdit control that will hold all data together. After that, use `EM_REPLACESEL` message to concatenate all the data together. Finally, use `EM_STREAMOUT` message to save all of the stream at one go.